# How to use enums to create generic API for Search and Filter of POJOs in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Lets say you have a particular enum called Field:

```
public enum Field {
    ALBUM,
    DESCRIPTION
}
```

And another enum called:

```
public enum Operator {

    CONTAINS,

    EQUALS,

    LESS_THAN,

    GREATER_THAN
}
```

And you have a corresponding Java interface called Music

```
public interface Music {
    String getAlbum();
    String getDescription();
}
```

Which the implementation looks liks this:

```
 public class MusicImpl implements Music {

     @Override
     public String getYear() {
         return Field.Year.toString();
     }

     @Override
     public String getDescription() {
         return Field.DESCRIPTION.toString();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getField(Field field) {
        Object myObject = field.getClass();
        return myObject;
     }  
}
```

How would you use this API to implement the following two methods?

```
public class MyApp {
    @Override
    public List<Music> searchMusic(String query) {
        // What to put in this?
    }

    @Override
    public List<Music> filterMusic(Field field, Operator op, String query) {
        // What to put in?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework you need to do?

Comment: Correct answer: won't compile

Comment: What exactly is `query` in `public List<Music> searchMusic(String query)`?

Comment: I think the line `Field.DESCRIPTION.toString()` will just return the string "DESCRIPTION". I'm fairly sure that's not what you want.

Comment: @Lars Blumberg Just trying a coding puzzle...@SpaceTrucker the query is just a String its not Hibernate / JPA.@Stewart thanks